# Value of -1 13/30

Tags: fractions

I've been working on this for a while now, I've searched the internet but I didn't get any valid solution.

The question
    What's the value of -1 13/30 (mixed fraction, -1, 13 by 30), is it -43/30 or -17/30.

I'm really confused, so any help with that would be very helpful.

Comment: What's the value of -1.7, is it -1.7 or is it -0.3?

Comment: Better phrased, is $-1.7$ equal to $-(1+0.7)$ or $-1 + 0.7$? They are different.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: People who tech the $1\frac12$ notation for $1.5=\frac32$ should fall on a knife while strolling in a dark alley. Even if said knife were held be a shady person who had received money to be in that exact location at that very moment.

Comment: Well Math SE is for all levels, and mixed numbers are often taught to students of younger years so that they can make sense of the fraction. Eventually the OP will move onto expressing answers in improper fractions, which are much easier to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$-1\frac{13}{30} = -(1\frac{13}{30}) = -(\frac{43}{30}) = -\frac{43}{30} $

Note that this is different from

$-1+\frac{13}{30}$ which is $-\frac{17}{30}$

Answer (score 1):

$1 + \frac{13}{30}$ is a positive number. In this notation, $-\left(1 + \frac{13}{30}\right)$ is the negative of $1 + \frac{13}{30}$.

Therefore $-1 \frac{13}{30} = -\left(1 + \frac{13}{30} \right)$. Can you end it now?